# java Test show Error:Could not find or load main class Test

Tags: java, command

I am using `NetBeansIDE 8.0`

and installed jdk1.8.0_05

also I'm setting the PATH =C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin;

when runing cmd on win 7

```
java -version ,the result is:
java version "1.8.0_05"
Java<TM> SE Runtime Environment <build 1.8.0_05-b13>
Java HotSpot<TM> Client VM <build 25.5-b02,mixed mode,sharing>
```

then runing javac -version
the result is: `javac 1.8.0_05`

after that writing a test program and run it successfully on the netbeans.
then return back to cmd and change to the directory of the program

```
C:\NetBeansProjects\Test\src\test> javac Test.java
C:\NetBeansProjects\Test\src\test>java Test
Error:Could not find or load main class Test
```

---

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the classpath even if you only need the default directory

Try

```
java -cp . Test
```